# Change background from bottom to top on hover

Tags: css, background, css-transitions

How I can change the background-color on `a:hover` using a transition from the bottom to the top with a duration of 0.3s?

```
<ul>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**There is no way to (generically) apply a transition direction in CSS**. However, we can *work around* that limitation by using a pseudo element (or other method like how [this example](https://codepen.io/brandon4117/pen/ihIgE) uses gradients).

By using a pseudo element, which initially has a *visible* height of 0, we can transition the height from and to a desired direction when the link is hovered. It's best to use `transform: scale` for performance reasons, which means that we need to set our `transform-origin` to `bottom center` in this case to make sure it goes from bottom to top.

This approach is probably the most general, working with non-solid backgrounds and such, but does require a pseudo element or child element.

The CSS for that approach would be:

```
li {
    background: red;
}
a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    background: blue;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
a:hover::after {
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EcF8s/90/)

Comment: The pseudo element :after did worked for me with your DEMO. Thx

Comment: Perhaps the first line in the answer is now false simply because of browser improvements, but this codepen example proves that it's false to say that there's no way to apply a transition direction: https://codepen.io/brandon4117/pen/ihIgE

Comment: @shellscape No, the statement is still true. You can change the transform origin and transition an *element* in that way using transforms, but you cannot apply a transition direction by itself. For example, you cannot transition the opacity of an element from left to right without faking it (which is what your example does by using gradients)

Comment: If you replace that blue background with an image, you will see my point. It only works because the background color is solid using that method