# Simple menubar effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make this more smooth?

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

I would like an effect, where `.menu` gets filled with a color starting from the top.

I tried with css3 styling.

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   transition: all .5s ease-in;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 0px #424242;
}
```

Comment: What is not `smooth` about it?

Comment: like only comming from the top, like its slidering in the color

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659605/change-background-from-bottom-to-top-on-hover

Comment: Yes, but how do i modify this, so that the background of my container .menu gets filled with color, comming in from the top?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fg4r4erg/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uctcf405/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/emw6y114/